# Understanding 'del' with sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have written below code:

```
dict1 = {7: 'Java', 4: 'JavaScript', 3: 'Python', 1:"C#"}
 
dict2 = dict1
del dict1
 
print(dict2)
```

My understanding is that both `dict1` and `dict2` are referring to the same object.

So, when I delete the object using one reference then I should get `empty` `{}` `dictionary`, when printing using another reference.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-del_stmt): *"Deletion of a name removes the **binding** of that name"*.